# Extending an embedding of a subset into $\mathbb{R}^n$, $i_{j}: X_{j} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to a map $k_{j}:X \to S^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm reading tom Dieck's algebraic topology text, chapter 18, section 4, Euclidean Neighborhood Retracts.

Once I got to Lemma 18.4.5, which seems as an innocuous enough result, I got a bit confused.

Here's the statement, and here's the proof.

> **Lemma:** Let the Hausdorff space $X = X_{1} \cup \dots \cup X_{r}$ be a union of locally compact open subsets $X_{j}$ which are homeomorphic to a subset of a Euclidean space. Then $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subset of a Euclidean space.
>
> **Proof:** There exist embeddings $i_{j}:X_{j} \to \mathbb{R}^{n_{j}}$ as a closed subset (this is ok and is the result of an earlier lemma). **We extend $i_{j}$ to a continuous map $k_{j}:X \to S^{n_{j}} = \mathbb{R}^n_{j} \cup \{ \infty \} $ by setting $k_{j}(X \setminus X_{j}) = \{ \infty \}...$**

My question is: **why is this map continuous**? The only important part is proving continuity at points $x \in \partial X_{j}$. These points go to $\infty$ and every nbhd of those points intersects $X_{j}$... If $k_{j}$ were continuous, that would automatically mean that $i_{j}(X_{j})$ can't be bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is by construction from the "previous lemma" that you mentioned. Look at the proof, it should be there.

Indeed, there are only two ways for the image of $X_j$ to be a **closed** subset of $\Bbb R^{n_j}$:

- either you "send the boundary to infinity", which is by definition what *proper maps* do, and which is what is claimed to be done here,
- or you do weird things such as this one:

[image]

This is the image of a continuous embedding from an **open** interval such as $(0,1)$, but it's not proper and in such a case your proof above fails.

Comment: Yep, the embedding constructed in proposition 18.4.2 is such that it is easily proven that $k_{j}$ is continuous. I can't believe I didn't look at the particular case. Thanks!